# Can`t exit from program

Tags: python-3.x, exit, continue

Trying to exit the program by importing sys.exit(), break and ask == False, but nothing works. Full code [here](https://pastebin.com/uEiQGLV6)

```
#import sys


def body_cycle(*args):

    if option == "/":
        error_func_for_zero(first_number, second_number, option)
        print(division_option(first_number, second_number))
        print()
        print(begin)


def error_func_for_zero(*args):

    try:
       first_number / 0 or second_number / 0

    except ZeroDivisionError:
       print("YOU CANNOT DIVIDE BY ZERO!")
       print(begin)

def division_option(*args):

    return first_number / second_number


begin = " " 

while begin:

    print("Hello, I am calculator. ")  
    print("Please, enter your numbers (just integers) ! ")

    print()

    first_number = int(input("First number: "))

    print()

    second_number = int(input("Second number: "))

    print()

    option = input("Remember: you can't divide by zero.\nChoose your option (+, -, *, /): ")

    print(body_cycle(first_number, second_number, option))


ask = " "

while ask:

    exit_or_continue = input("If you want continue press 'Y', 'y'. For break press 'N' or 'n'? \nChoice: ")

    if exit_or_continue == "Y" or "y":
       print("OK")

    elif exit_or_continue == "N" or "n":  
       #break
       ask == False

    else:
       print("Break program. ")
       break
```

Comment: Your `ask == False` is faulty and is equivalent to writing just `False` on a line, which doesn't do anything of course. You want to use `ask = False` to assign a new value...

Comment: Understood. Thanks

Comment: You meen:
elif exit_or_continue == "N" or "n":  
     #break
     ask = False

Comment: No problem. Yes that line. Also can I ask why you need two loops? One loop with the following inputs: "number1, number2, operation, do you want to continue?" would work nicely. Because right now I'm pretty sure you have an infinite `while begin` loop.

Comment: Also you cannot write `something == "N" or "n"`. You need to use either `something == "N" or something == "n"` or `something in ("N", "n")`. To disregard case entirely, you can also check just the lower case version `if something.lower() == "n":`.

Comment: You absolutely right, I have been infinite loop in line “while True” and I didn`t know what doing wrong. 
Dude, you are cool, more one week it`s was my problems but you showed me on my mistakes. I still have a lot to learn. Thanks)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to replace `ask == False` by `ask  = False`.

In addition, you could really use a simpler code structure. The whole thing before `begin` can be compacted down to:

```
def operation(a, b, option):

    if option == "+":
        return a + b

    elif option == "-":
        return a - b

    elif option == "*":
        return a * b

    elif option == "/":
        try:
            return a / b
        except ZeroDivsionError
            return "YOU CANNOT DIVIDE BY ZERO!"
```

The rest can be put in a single loop instead of two, like so:

```
print("Hello, I am calculator. ")  

while True:
    print("Please, enter your numbers (just integers) ! ")
    print()

    first_number = int(input("First number: "))
    print()

    second_number = int(input("Second number: "))
    print()

    option = input("Remember: you can't divide by zero.\n
                    Choose your option (+, -, *, /): ")

    # Result.
    print(operation(first_number, second_number, option))

    exit_or_continue = input("If you want continue press 'Y', 'y'. For break press 'N' or 'n'.\n
                              Choice: ").lower()

    if exit_or_continue == "y":
       print("OK")

    elif exit_or_continue == "n":
       break
```